# Karate - Mock Server feature use of background

Tags: mocking, netty, karate

I have a difficult microservice under test which interacts with 10+ downstream services. There is much logic and permutations which exist so trying to come up with an automated solution is tricky. I am trying to move away from the current cucumber/java & templates wiremock solution as I feel is overly complicated which limits black box coverage.

I was using the mock server before and I found I couldn’t set constant variables in the background which could be utilised to each feature or overwritten when writing in that constant with the scenario itself. I understand scenario outline is not permitted within the mock server and I was hoping to set constants in the background to save space duplicating the same constants over and over throughout separate scenarios.

Did I do something incorrect? Is something like this possible?
I am using karate 1.4.0

Comment: besides the answer someone posted which is pretty good advice (call a second feature or js or json) you can look at this alternate mocking approach that gives you more code-driven power: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Karate-JavaScript-Mocks

Answer (score 0):

> "I was hoping to set constants in the background to save space duplicating the same constants over and over throughout separate scenarios."

You could set all the constants in the karate.config.js which would then be available for use globally in the test suite. Refer to the documentation here please: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configuration

Another options for this is setting all the constants in a separate feature file and then doing a call/read on the constants feature file from within the feature you need to use the constants in.

Create a constants feature file called `constants.feature`

```
def constValue = "constant"
```

Now you can call that feature in the background

```
* call read(constants.feature)
```

And access them like so

```
* match constValue == "constant"
```

A couple things to note are

- If called within the Background, the values will be re-initialized with every scenario - you can use the callonce hook to avoid this behavior - [callonce](https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks)

> or overwritten when writing in that constant with the scenario itself.

- you can use [karate.set](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate?tab=readme-ov-file#karate-setpath) to over-ride the constant values if needed but please be aware that you should not expect to have the same var from one scenario to the next. Every scenario should be executable by itself without dependency on any other scenario.

Comment: I should've looked more closely at the notes
it clearly states the background (which logically makes sense) gets set pre-test execution but is not executed before each Scenario.

All i simply did to resolve my issue was to create a standard mock response which is utilized for common data returns. And for slightly tweaks, I created a configurable mock response which I then over-write with values defined in that particular mock scenario.

Im yet to look into the js (karate) mock capability



This ticket should be closed

Answer (score 0):

I should've looked more closely at the notes
it clearly states the background (which logically makes sense) gets set pre-test execution but is not executed before each Scenario.

All i simply did to resolve my issue was to create a standard mock response which is utilized for common data returns. And for slightly tweaks, I created a configurable mock response which I then over-write with values defined in that particular mock scenario.

I could've also called the config.js file and reset data back to initial state.

I'm yet to look into the js (karate) mock capability

for those interested see below

```
`Scenario: karate.request.header('uuid') == '9a19-b4f4871f5289'
* def NAME1_NBR = "122979"
* def NAME2_NBR = ""
* def response = read('./mockResponses/response_configurable.json')
* print response`

`Scenario: pathMatches('/cypress/x/link')
* def response = read('./mockResponses/response_standard.json')
* print response`

`Scenario: pathMatches('/xpress/r/servicelink/v1.0.0/30/uta')
* def response = read('./mockResponses/uta/utaResponse.json')`
```

Comment: This should be closed